# Define an S4 class with slots that have their class definitions in another package

Tags: r, class, r-s4

I would like to define an S4 class in R. One of the slots should contain an `mcmc` object as defined in the `coda` package. I tried the following:

```
library("coda")
setClass(Class = "myClass", representation = representation(var = "mcmc"))
```

But this results in a warning:

> Undefined slot classes in the definition of "myClass": var(class "mcmc")

The class definition does not work later on and throws an error message because `var` has an "undefined class".

How can I tell the `setClass` command where to look for the definition of `mcmc` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because `mcmc` is an S3 class and not a formal `S4` class.  You would need to use `setOldClass` to register the `S3` as a formally defined class.

```
setOldClass("mcmc")
setClass(Class = "myClass", representation = representation(var = "mcmc"))
```